# C# 2 dimensional array summing and checking values to return true or false bool

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a 2d array (size of which is input by the user) fill it with int (in numerical order), then sum all columns, rows and diagonals to see if they are the same, at which point a boolean value is true or false? Practising for a job interview but this one has snagged me!Thanks

```
int[,] n;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int row = number;
int column = number;                    
n = new int[row, column];

int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
      {
           for (j = 0; j < column - 1; j++)
           {
               n[i, j] = i + 1;                            
           }
```

Comment: And what aspect of this problem are you struggling with?  What parts have you been able to do successfully?

Comment: sorry forgot the code

Comment: So what problem(s) are you having with this code?

Comment: i now cant figure out how to sum the rows, columns and diagonals?

Comment: @user3242281 What have you done to try to sum each of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this, I'm not sure if correct but you got the idea.

```
        var array = new int[10,10];
        int sum = 0;

        // Fill array
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                array[i, j] = i + j*10;

        // Sum horizontal
        var sumRows = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                sumRows[i] += array[i, j];

        // Sum vertical
        var sumColumns = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                sumColumns[j] += array[i, j];

        // Diagonal A
        int diagonalA = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                if (i == j) diagonalA += array[i, j];

        // Diagonal B
        int diagonalB = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                if (10-i-1 == j) diagonalB += array[i, j];
```